# Как Windows устанавливает драйвер USB-устройства?

Tags: usb, драйвер, libusb

Собрал USB-устройство (CDC), сделал к нему драйвер (inf, cat, sys, dll) с помощью libusb. Он нормально устанавливается через диспетчер устройств. Но Windows каким-то образом автоматически устанавливает драйверы на флешки, на принтеры и другие устройства, подключаемые к шине USB. Откуда они берутся? Они находятся в контроллере флешки? Как мне загрузить драйвер в мой контроллер, чтобы он автоматически установился в Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows автоматически устанавливает только те драйвера, которые у неё есть. Часть драйверов для самых распространённых устройств идёт в комплекте с самой ОС, часть - это драйвера для ранее установленных устройств, часть она находит в БД Микрософта через Windows Update. В контроллере флешки нет и не может быть никаких драйверов. Максимум что можно сделать - добавить к устройству виртуальный CD-ROM, на котором будет требуемый драйвер.

Answer (score 1):

Винда может использовать для устройства т.н. class driver - драйвер для целого класса устройств. Например, в usbstor.inf есть строка "USB\Class_08&SubClass_02&Prot_50", которая указывает, что для USB-устройства с классом 8 (Mass storage, основная спецификация на USB), субклассом 2 (ATAPI, спецификация на Mass Storage class) и протоколом 50 (Mass storage bulk only, тоже спека на Mass Storage class) нужно загрузить USBSTOR.SYS независимо от конкретных VID/PID. Но если будет найден драйвер по VID-PID - загружен будет именно он.